# 'image' attribute has no file associated with it - django

Tags: python, django, image

I have a blog project, and receive the above error when running the django dev server. I have uploaded an image via the admin panel, which then saves as expected in the posts/media folder. Please can anyone help?

My project (shortened version) looks as follows:

```
 - blogproject
     - posts 
         - media
         - static
         - templates
             - posts
             - base.html
             - getAllPosts.html
    - blog
        - urls.py
        - settings.py
        - models.py
```

> SETTINGS.PY

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR, ]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'posts/media')
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

> URLS.PY

```
[...]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, 
document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

> models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    category = models.ManyToManyField('Category')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=True)
    titleSlug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    authorSlug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/%Y/%m/%d", null=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.titleSlug = slugify(self.title)
    self.authorSlug = slugify(self.author)
    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

> getAllPosts.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "posts/base.html" %} 
{% load static %}
{% load template_tags %}

{% block content %} 
{% if latest_posts %}
   {% for post in latest_posts %}

   <a href="{% url 'getPost' slug=post.titleSlug %}">
      <img src="{{ MEDIA.URL }} {{post.image.url}}" alt="image-
{{post.title}}"/>
   </a>
```

Comment: Have you uploaded any images

Comment: Totally unrelated, but your MEDIA_ROOT should be _outside_ your project's source tree. Also, `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'posts/media')` kind of defeats the whole point of using `os.path.join()`, which is to avoid harcoding path separators. You want `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'posts', 'media')` instead.

Comment: Post your view function

Comment: Are you sure that ALL the posts saved in the database have an image uploaded? I can see that the image attribute can be null, maybe one of the posts saved in the database has no image. In that case, you only need to make the verification in the template before displaying the image.

Comment: Thank you @Nazkter - that worked! I only had one image for the latest post. Thank you very much I've been stuck on this for days

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thank you I will fix :-)